Откат проекта в Pycharm
Хотел загрузить свой проект на гит. Но выбрал другое и вот теперь страдаю.
Я случайно загрузил другой проект в свой проект, при этом файлы заменились полностью, так как были одинаковые названия.
Пробовал откатить с помощью Local history, но там файлы после того как я уже совершил ошибку.
Загрузка произошла в 17:04 файлы видна в изображении.
Во втором изображении нажал ctl+alt+z но это не помогло и вернулись только те файлы, которые были удалены, а измененные остались.
Вопрос: Как откатить до 17:00 до загрузки из Git


